# FMDB database read using multithreading

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I am using FMDB database library for sqlite in iOS. How can I perform multiple read operation simultaneously in FMDB. Currently I am using FMDB database queue.

Answer (score 1):

FMDB Queue works fine with multi threading. currently i am using it with my application in multi threading and found no issues.

please describe what problem you are facing with FMDB queue

### example

```
      var queue = FMDatabaseQueue(path:"db path")

      queue.inTransaction{ (db, rollback) in
        do
        {
            let resultset = try db.executeQuery(queryString, values: [])
            while(resultset.next()){
                //do your task

             }

        }
        catch
        {
            rollback.memory = true
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

FMDatabaseQueue serializes all database accesses. You can't perform multiple read operation simultaneously with FMDatabaseQueue, and never will: this is not the purpose of FMDatabaseQueue.

FMDB does not provide any other safe concurrency model, unfortunately. You can use a raw FMDatabase connection, and deal yourself with write serialization, and parallel reads. For example, you can wrap your database calls in a concurrent DispatchQueue:

```
let dbQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "database", attributes: .concurrent)
func read(block: () -> ()) {
    // Since the queue is concurrent, several readers can execute at
    // the same time.
    dbQueue.sync(execute: block)
}
func write(block: () -> ()) {
    // The barrier flag makes sure that only one writer block is executing
    // at a given time, and that no reader is currently executing.
    dbQueue.sync(flags: .barrier, execute: block)
}

let db = FMDatabase(...)
read {
    // Select from db
}
write {
    // Write in db
}
```

This solution has caveats, though: the number of concurrent reads is not limited, you don't profit from DatabaseQueue high-level APIs around transactions or savepoints, and the `read` method does not prevent you from executing database updates.

You can check an alternative to FMDB: the [GRDB.swift](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) library. It is quite similar to FMDB. Unlike FMDB, though, it provides a DatabasePool class that avoids all caveats listed above: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift#database-pools

```
let dbPool = DatabasePool(path: ...)

// Serialized writes
try dbPool.write { db in
    try db.execute("CREATE TABLE ...")
    try db.execute("INSERT INTO ...")
}

// Concurrent reads
dbPool.read { db in
    for row in Row.fetch(db, "SELECT * FROM ...") {
        ...
    }
    let count = Int.fetchOne(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...")!
}
```

Comment: FMDB have also DatabasePool, for what purpose ?

Comment: FMDB's DatabasePool is nothing like GRDB's DatabasePool, despite their identical name. FMDB DatabasePool is [dangerous](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/9a98636848905f48b6b9a304f2b90f9b3c2c9c4a/src/fmdb/FMDatabasePool.h#L15-L31), when GRDB DatabasePool is rock-solid.

Answer (score -1):

check this link is useful for you:

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift

To get data:

@IBAction func findContact(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

```
if (contactDB?.open())! {
    let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = '\(name.text!)'"

    let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB?.executeQuery(querySQL,
                                           withArgumentsIn: nil)

    if results?.next() == true {
        address.text = results?.string(forColumn: "address")
        phone.text = results?.string(forColumn: "phone")
        status.text = "Record Found"
    } else {
        status.text = "Record not found"
        address.text = ""
        phone.text = ""
    }
    contactDB?.close()
} else {
    print("Error: \(contactDB?.lastErrorMessage())")
}
```

}